# imap beginning with <C-o> interferes with omnicomplete

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, insert-mode

I added the following key mappings:

```
inoremap <silent> <Up>   <C-o>gk
inoremap <silent> <Down> <C-o>gj
```

The goal was that `j`/`k` would still work the way that I was used to, but that I could use the arrow keys as an alternative to more easily navigate wrapped lines.  Now I've discovered that these mappings interfere with omnicompletion.  If I hit an arrow key, `<C-o>` ends the omnicomplete, and `gj` (or `gk`) is inserted at the cursor position.

I found an mailing list exchange from 2006 where Bram [acknowledges the issue](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Bug-or-feature-Mappings-in-omni-completion-popup-menu-td1196760.html), but can't find any mention of it more recently.  Is this still an unresolved issue?  Is there any way to make imap bindings beginning with `<C-o>` compatible with omnicompletion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the more powerful "expression mappings":

```
:inoremap <expr> <silent> <Up>   pumvisible() ? "\<Up>" : "\<C-o>gk"
:inoremap <expr> <silent> <Down> pumvisible() ? "\<Down>" : "\<C-o>gj"
```

Note that we added the `<expr>` keyword here. Now Vim expects that the right-hand is some (valid) VimScript expression. This expression is evaluated every time the key is pressed and the result is used as the action.

Here we use the [`pumvisible()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#pumvisible%28%29) function (short for "pop-up menu visible") to check if the popup menu is visible. If it is, just go up/down. If it isn't, use your special mappings.

Also see [`:help :map-expression`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-expression).

---

Expression mappings were introduced with Vim 7, which was released in May 2006 (after the maillist post you linked to), which is why no one mentioned this as a solution back then :-)

Comment: I know a lot has changed in Vim since 2006. I was more surprised that nobody has had this question (or at least, asked it in a place that I was able to find within a few minutes of googling) since then...

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**:

```
inoremap <up> <c-\><c-o>gk
inoremap <down> <c-\><c-o>gj
```

The difference is: I added `<c-\>`.

While Carpetsmoker's solution is also nice, I found that the solution might not work in some cases.

For example, when pop-up menu is not visible but we are still in the omni-completion mode (when we type or just select the suggested item, the pop-up menu disappears but the command line reads `Omni completion (^O^N^P)`), a consequent `<c-o>` will work as an omnicomplete-related command, not special keys in insert mode.

From [`:help ins-special-special`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ins-special-special):

```
CTRL-O          execute one command, return to Insert mode   i_CTRL-O
CTRL-\ CTRL-O   like CTRL-O but don't move the cursor        i_CTRL-\_CTRL-O
```

which shows that `<c-\><c-o>` is another way to achieve the same behavior like `<ctrl-o>`. Using the aforementioned key mapping, I see that navigation using arrow keys in the insert mode does work without conflicting to omni-completion mode.